# Config nginx to reverse proxy for mqtt communication

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, proxy, mqtt

I have an MQTT (EMQX) server running on an ip and a port. And I communicate directly between my service and that port using the nodejs MQTT library.

I want to use a reverse proxy (nginx) to be able to use a DNS in order to prune the communication.

At this moment my nginx is configured like this:

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

stream {

    upstream websocket {
        server ******:7053;
    }
 
    server {

        listen 8888;
 
        proxy_pass websocket;


    }
}

http {

    server {
        
        listen 884;
        server_name *******;.
        error_log /var/log/errors.log;
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass *******;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

        }

    } 

}
```

So when I try to connect through port 8888 the nginx always timeout

```
2020/12/03 16:23:48 [error] 22#22: *31 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.155.0.10, server: 0.0.0.0:8888, upstream: "192.16.102.26:7053", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

both services are in docker containers. and are started by a docker compose.

the compose for MQTT service is:

```
version: "2.1"


services:

  mqtt-broker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: evio_mqtt_broker
    environment:
      - EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL=8883
      - EMQX_DASHBOARD__LISTENER__HTTP=18083

      - EMQX_LOADED_PLUGINS="emqx_auth_username,emqx_recon,emqx_retainer,emqx_management,emqx_dashboard"

      - EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__TLS_VERSIONS=tlsv1.2
      #- EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__KEYFILE=etc/certs/key.pem
      #- EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__CERTFILE=etc/certs/cert.pem
      #- EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__CACERTFILE=etc/certs/cacert.pem
      - EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__VERIFY=verify_peer
      #- EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT=true
      - EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__REUSE_SESSIONS=on
      - EMQX_LISTENER__SSL__EXTERNAL__HONOR_CIPHER_ORDER=on

      - EMQX_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=false
      - EMQX_AUTH__USER__1__USERNAME=****
      - EMQX_AUTH__USER__1__PASSWORD=****
      #- EMQX_AUTH__USER__2__USERNAME=umdc
      #- EMQX_AUTH__USER__2__PASSWORD=umdc_buddy

      - EMQX_DASHBOARD__DEFAULT_USER__PASSWORD=****
    ports:
      - "7053:1883"   # MQTT Port
      - "8883:8883"   # MQTT SSL Port
      #- "8083:8083"   # MQTT WebSocket Port
      #- "8084:8084"   # MQTT WebSocket SSL Port
      #- "8080:8080"   # HTPP Management Port
      - "1884:18083" # Web Dashboard Port
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "50m"
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - evio_network
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

networks:
    evio_network:
```

and for nginx are:

```
version: "2.0"

networks:
  evio_network:

services:
  reverse_proxy:
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - evio_network
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 8843:8843
      - 1883:1883
      - 8883:8883
    volumes:
      - /home/evio/src/evio_nginx_reverse_proxy/config/nginxDEV.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    restart: always
```

Do I have to change anything in mqtt or is something wrong with my reverse proxy?

Comment: sorry the ip is 172.16.102.26, which is the ip of the machine where the two containers are and port 7053 is the port of the MQTT container

Comment: Yes i use docker compose.

Comment: Why are they in 2 separate files? and you probably should be using container names as hostnames so you don't need to know what IP addresses they end up with.

Comment: I don't think docker compose works that way, because they are in separate files they will be running on separate networks (one for each orchestration).  Try running `docker network list` I bet you will have 2 separate `evio_network`

Comment: Although mqtt and nginx are on the same physical machine they are in different files because each one is in a separate folder on the machine. Since when you restart a container you don't have to turn off and on both

Comment: Yes we have two networks. have to be on the same network?

Comment: Both services should be in the same file as they are part of the same orchestration, you can still restart individual services independently of each other. It will also ensure they are both on the same network (since you are not using an "external" )

Comment: It is not directly related, but I've found this amazing implementation of Ngnix + MQTT https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-and-iot-adding-protocol-awareness-for-mqtt/#018streamnginScriptandMQTT including application protocol awareness clustered mqtt load balancing and TLS offload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments.

The problem here was that the 2 services were being started from seperate docker-compose files. While they were both binding to networks with the same name, those networks were separate because they were being prefixed by different orchestration names.

There are 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Combine the 2 docker compose files, this will mean that they are then in the same namespace and will share the common named network.
2. Create a "external" network and reference this from both files.

For the second option you use the `docker network` command to create the network, e.g. `docker network create evio_network` and then at the end of each compose file include the following:

```
networks:
  evio_network:
    external:
      name: "evio_network"
```